# Python Threading duplicate dictionnary result

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I am trying to debug a code that ping a list of hosts by threading.

Result is fine on the first start() call of the class.
On the subsequent calls ( start() ), I get duplicates in the dictionnary.

Sample result :

> INFO:**main**:[u'192.168.1.71', u'192.168.1.70']
>
> INFO:**main**:Starting watchdog, poll interval set to 15 minutes / 15 seconds
>
> INFO:**main**:set([u'192.168.1.71', u'192.168.1.70'])
>
> INFO:**main**:Pinging IPs...
>
> INFO:**main**:{'dead': [u'192.168.1.70', u'192.168.1.70'], 'alive': [u'192.168.1.71', u'192.168.1.71']}
>
> INFO:**main**:Sleeping...

Anyone can help ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import threading

class Pinger(object):

    status = {'alive': [], 'dead': []} # Populated while we are running

    hosts = [] # List of all hosts/ips in our input queue

    # How many ping process at the time.
    thread_count = 4

    # Lock object to keep track the threads in loops, where it can potentially be race conditions.
    lock = threading.Lock()

    def ping(self, ip):
        # Use the system ping command with count of 1 and wait time of 1.
        ret = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c', '2', '-W', '1', ip],
                          stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'), 
        stderr=open('/dev/null', 'w'))

        return ret == 0 # Return True if our ping command succeeds

    def pop_queue(self):
        ip = None

        self.lock.acquire() # Grab or wait+grab the lock.

        if self.hosts:
            ip = self.hosts.pop()

        self.lock.release() # Release the lock, so another thread could grab it.

        return ip

    def dequeue(self):
        while True:
            ip = self.pop_queue()

            if not ip:
                return None

            result = 'alive' if self.ping(ip) else 'dead'
            self.status[result].append(ip)

    def start(self):
        threads = []
    
        for i in range(self.thread_count):
            # Create self.thread_count number of threads that together will
            # cooperate removing every ip in the list. Each thread will do the
            # job as fast as it can.
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.dequeue)
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)
        

        # Wait until all the threads are done. .join() is blocking.
        [ t.join() for t in threads ]

        return self.status

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ping = Pinger()
    ping.thread_count = 8
    ping.hosts = [
        '10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2', '10.0.0.3', '10.0.0.4', '10.0.0.0', 
        '10.0.0.255', '10.0.0.100', 'google.com', 'github.com', 
        'nonexisting', '127.0.1.2', '*not able to ping!*', '8.8.8.8'
    ]

    print ping.start()
```

Comment: in def ping.. you comment count of 1 and wait time of 1.. but in the code you have '2' .. change to '1' maybe?

Comment: `self.status[result].append(ip)` is not locked.

Comment: In `def start` is the indentation correct? It looks like you run `join` inside the loop.

Comment: Yes the indentation is correct, sorry a type when I was copying it

Answer (score 0):

Using `multiprocessing.Pool` will make your life easier. You can accomplish the same thing with:

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess

hosts = [
    '10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2', '10.0.0.3', '10.0.0.4', '10.0.0.0', '10.0.0.255', '10.0.0.100',
    'google.com', 'github.com', 'nonexisting', '127.0.1.2', '*not able to ping!*', '8.8.8.8'
]

def ping(host):
    print("pinging", host)
    ret = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c', '2', '-W', '1', host],
                          stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'), stderr=open('/dev/null', 'w'))
    return (host, ret == 0)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8)

out = {'dead': [], 'alive': []}

for host, alive in pool.map(ping, hosts):
    if alive:
        out['alive'].append(host)
    else:
        out['dead'].append(host)

print(out)
```

If for some reason you need to use threads rather than processes, you can utilize the same functionality via the (poorly named) `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` instead of `multiprocessing.Pool`:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
```

Otherwise, the usage is exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the input.

I will try it but what should I do to debug my existing code ?

Someone suggested to "lock" ?